# How can I view not-accessible SNMP indexes? MPLS implementation

Tags: cisco, snmp, mpls

We are trying to rebuild a few cisco show commands with SNMP OID information. Right now i'm working on MPLS and i'm trying to get the In/Out label info. I keep running into the same problem, the information I need is help by indexes that are marked "not-accessible". For example the `MplsInSegmentLabel` and `MplsInSegmentIfIndex`. Is there a way I can view the information on these OIDs and indexes? I know my understanding of SNMP might not be complete enough but I would appreciate any help or even a push in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

It may happen that the OID`s you are querying are not implemented on the device. It may happen that either those are not supported or not implemented.

Just in case for your verification you can use "-Cc" option of snmpwalk which will give you the whole MIB.